# Screenshot with Katalon and Chrome headless mode

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, headless, katalon

Copying/reposting from stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168671/screenshot-with-katalon-and-chrome-headless-mode.

I'm using the following code to take screenshots of warning and error messages in my Katalon Studio scripts:

```
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.coordinates.*
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.cropper.*

public class ScreenshotHelper {


  public void takeWebElementScreenshot(TestObject object) {
    WebElement element = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(object, 20)
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmSSS").format(new Date())
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver, element)
    ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(),'PNG', new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ErrorScreenshots/ElementScreenshot"+"_"+fileName+".png"))
  }
}
```

This method gets called from another method of the same class:

```
public void catchNotyMessage(){

TestObject noty_warning = WebUI.modifyObjectProperty(findTestObject("DUMMY"), 'css', 'equals', 'div.noty_type_warning', true)
TestObject noty_error = WebUI.modifyObjectProperty(findTestObject("DUMMY"), 'css', 'equals', 'div.noty_type_error', true)

    if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(noty_error, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
        this.takeWebElementScreenshot(noty_error)
    }
    else if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(noty_warning, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
        this.takeWebElementScreenshot(noty_warning)
    }
}
```

And it works fine, the screenshot gets taken when using Katalon in normal mode.

However, when I run the script in headless mode, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/DUMMY' located by 'By.cssSelector: div.noty_type_error' not found
```

even though the element should be present. And the test fails with the **java.lang.NullPointerException**.

Is is because of the headless execution? If so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871955/java-io-filenotfoundexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600505/chrome-headless-doesnt-work
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239130/java-user-dir-property-what-exactly-does-it-mean,
  i finally figured it out.

The problem is that `System.getProperty("user.dir")` changes when the test gets executed via *command line* in headless mode. So, this code works:

```
    public void takeWebElementScreenshot(TestObject object) {
    WebElement element = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(object, 20)
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmSSS").format(new Date())
    Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver, element)
    try {
        if (DriverFactory.getExecutedBrowser().getName()=='HEADLESS_DRIVER'){
            ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(),'PNG', new File("C:/Users/path_to_working_directory/ErrorScreenshots/HeadlessElementScreenshot"+"_"+fileName+".png"))
        } else {
            ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(),'PNG', new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ErrorScreenshots/ElementScreenshot"+"_"+fileName+".png"))
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```